# Split slider with responsive feature

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, slider

I came across a nice splider slider and wanted to change it behaviour so that when slider is on smaller screen below 768 pixels then image should show on top and text below. when i tried to play around it just broke the design.

Is there any easy way to modify this Slider to desired behaviour.

https://codepen.io/veronicadev/pen/yjgjvL

i tried to add Media query but it not making any difference to design

```
@media (max-width:767px)
{
  .carousel-item__image{  width: 100%;}
  .carousel-item__info{width: 100%;}
}
```

```js
$(function(){
  $('.carousel-item').eq(0).addClass('active');
  var total = $('.carousel-item').length;
  var current = 0;
  $('#moveRight').on('click', function(){
    var next=current;
    current= current+1;
    setSlide(next, current);
  });
  $('#moveLeft').on('click', function(){
    var prev=current;
    current = current- 1;
    setSlide(prev, current);
  });
  function setSlide(prev, next){
    var slide= current;
    if(next>total-1){
     slide=0;
      current=0;
    }
    if(next<0){
      slide=total - 1;
      current=total - 1;
    }
           $('.carousel-item').eq(prev).removeClass('active');
           $('.carousel-item').eq(slide).addClass('active');
      setTimeout(function(){

      },800);
    

    
    console.log('current '+current);
    console.log('prev '+prev);
  }
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display:400,400i,700,700i,900,900i');

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i');


* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    justify-content: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
}

body {
    background-color: #eaeaea;
}

.carousel {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    max-width: 900px;
    max-height: 450px;   
    overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.carousel-item {
  visibility:visible;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end;
      -webkit-align-items: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fff;
    flex-shrink: 0;
   -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
  transition: 0.6s all linear;
}

.carousel-item__info {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  
    display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  
  order: 1;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0 40px;
  width: 40%;

}

.carousel-item__image {
    width: 60%;
    height: 100%;
    order: 2;
    align-self: flex-end;
    flex-basis: 60%;
  
      -webkit-order: 2;
    -webkit-align-self: flex-end;
    -webkit-flex-basis: 60%;
  
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
   position:relative;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  transition: 0.6s all ease-in-out;
}

.carousel-item__subtitle {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-size: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 0;
    color: #7E7E7E;    
    font-weight: 700;
    transform: translateY(25%);
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: 0.4s all ease-in-out;
}

.carousel-item__title {
    margin: 15px 0 0 0;
    font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
    font-size: 44px;
    line-height: 45px;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #2C2C2C;
    transform: translateY(25%);
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: 0.6s all ease-in-out;
}

.carousel-item__description {
    transform: translateY(25%);
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: 0.6s all ease-in-out;
    margin-top: 35px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #7e7e7e;
    line-height: 22px;
    margin-bottom: 35px;
}

.carousel-item--1 .carousel-item__image{
  background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/991012/pexels-photo-991012.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940');
}


.carousel-item--2 .carousel-item__image{
  background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/921294/pexels-photo-921294.png?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260');
}

.carousel-item--3 .carousel-item__image{
  background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/92733/pexels-photo-92733.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260');
}

.carousel-item--4 .carousel-item__image{
  background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/1008732/pexels-photo-1008732.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260');
}

.carousel-item--5 .carousel-item__image{
  background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/1029614/pexels-photo-1029614.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940');
}




.carousel-item__container{

}

.carousel-item__btn {
    width: 35%;
    color: #2C2C2C;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 0;
    width: 35%;
    font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
      transform: translateY(25%);
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: 0.6s all ease-in-out;
}

.carousel__nav {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: #fff;
  bottom: 0;
}

.carousel__icon {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 16px;
  fill: #5d5d5d;
}

.carousel__arrow {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 11px 15px;
    position: relative;
}

.carousel__arrow:nth-child(1):after {
    content:'';
    right: -3px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    background-color: #b0b0b0;
    height: 14px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -7px;
}

.active{
   z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  visibility:visible;
}

.active .carousel-item__subtitle, .active .carousel-item__title, .active .carousel-item__description,.active .carousel-item__btn{
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.6s all ease-in-out;
    visibility: visible;
}



.active .carousel-item__image{ 
transition: 0.6s all ease-in-out;
transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
  <title>FlexBox Exercise #3 - Image carousel / Responsive </title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
<div class="carousel">
  <div class="carousel__nav">
   <span id="moveLeft" class="carousel__arrow">
        <svg class="carousel__icon" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <path d="M20,11V13H8L13.5,18.5L12.08,19.92L4.16,12L12.08,4.08L13.5,5.5L8,11H20Z"></path>
</svg>
    </span>
    <span id="moveRight" class="carousel__arrow" >
      <svg class="carousel__icon"  width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
  <path d="M4,11V13H16L10.5,18.5L11.92,19.92L19.84,12L11.92,4.08L10.5,5.5L16,11H4Z"></path>
</svg>    
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item carousel-item--1">
    <div class="carousel-item__image"></div>
    <div class="carousel-item__info">
      <div class="carousel-item__container">
      <h2 class="carousel-item__subtitle">The grand moment </h2>
      <h1 class="carousel-item__title">Le tour</h1>
      <p class="carousel-item__description">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
      <a href="#" class="carousel-item__btn">Explore the tour</a>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item carousel-item--2">
    <div class="carousel-item__image"></div>
    <div class="carousel-item__info">
      <div class="carousel-item__container">
      <h2 class="carousel-item__subtitle">The big window </h2>
      <h1 class="carousel-item__title">Minimal window</h1>
      <p class="carousel-item__description">Clear Glass Window With Brown and White Wooden Frame iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium.</p>
      <a href="#" class="carousel-item__btn">Read the article</a>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="carousel-item carousel-item--3">
    <div class="carousel-item__image"></div>
    <div class="carousel-item__info">
      <div class="carousel-item__container">
      <h2 class="carousel-item__subtitle">Tropical palms </h2>
      <h1 class="carousel-item__title">Palms</h1>
      <p class="carousel-item__description">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
      <a href="#" class="carousel-item__btn">Explore the palms</a>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
   <div class="carousel-item carousel-item--4">
    <div class="carousel-item__image"></div>
    <div class="carousel-item__info">
      <div class="carousel-item__container">
      <h2 class="carousel-item__subtitle">Beach </h2>
      <h1 class="carousel-item__title">The beach </h1>
      <p class="carousel-item__description">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
      <a href="#" class="carousel-item__btn">Explore the beach</a>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
 <div class="carousel-item carousel-item--5">
    <div class="carousel-item__image"></div>
    <div class="carousel-item__info">
      <div class="carousel-item__container">
      <h2 class="carousel-item__subtitle">The white building </h2>
      <h1 class="carousel-item__title">White building</h1>
      <p class="carousel-item__description">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
      <a href="#" class="carousel-item__btn">Read the article</a>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px){
  .carousel-item{flex-direction:column}
  .carousel-item__image{width: 100%; order:1}
  .carousel-item__info{width: 100%;}
}
```

increasing `width:100%` won't make any changes, since the div is in `display:flex` mode. You need to change the direction of the `flex`. Also their `order:/*1 or 0*/`

You can check this [link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to understand how a flexbox works.

Comment: it looks fine but i want to split both both image & info box with 50vh but its not working as images take around 60vh for mobile version... `@media only screen and (max-width: 767px){
  .carousel-item{flex-direction:column}
  .carousel-item__image{width: 100%; height:50vh; order:1;
    -webkit-flex-basis: 100%; 
    background-position: center;background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;}
  .carousel-item__info{width: 100%; height:50vh;}
  .carousel {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    max-width: 1180px;
    max-height: 100vh;   
}

}`

Comment: https://codepen.io/KGuide/pen/VwQWmwR

Comment: Managed to fix it by removing `    -webkit-flex-basis: 100%; `

Comment: @student which screen size is for the mobile? on the codepen link, you shared both image and infobox show as 50vh.

Comment: i mean image & text should take about 80vh, 40vh for `carousel-item__image` & 40vh for  `carousel-item__info` but when i added header section on top it shows on top of header. i want carousal to show exactly below Header `.spacer` div for both desktop version as well as mobile version

Comment: @student okay, I didn't get the header section earlier to check on. anyway, I am glad it worked for you.

Comment: Carousal is still overlapping on Header section on mobile version i am trying to fix it, it has something to do with flex

Comment: which browser and which screen size? and is it still on the codepen you are working

Comment: I am testing it for FF and my screenshot is 1920x180 but i use devtool plugin to test the responsiveness same happens in codepen window also when you resize change view section

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244893/discussion-between-sumeshsn1-and-student).

Comment: Thanks, I have fixed it now by making some changes, i will update the code and mark your answer as correct as it helped me get started..